# Unable to translate SQL query to LINQ using EF

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework, linq

I have a query that in SQL looks like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ORDERS o, CUSTOMERS c 
WHERE 
(several conditions)
AND o.NUMBER NOT IN 
    (SELECT o.NUMBER
    FROM ORDERS o, CUSTOMERS c 
    WHERE 
    (exactly the same conditions as above)
    GROUP BY o.NUMBER
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

My try at doing this in LINQ isn't returning the same results than the SQL query. This is what I'm doing:

```
var query = (from o in context.ORDERS
             from c in context.CUSTOMERS
             where (bunch of conditions) &&
                    (from o in context.ORDERS
                     from c in context.CUSTOMERS
                     where (bunch of conditions)
                     group o by o.NUMBER into grp
                     where grp.Count() > 1
                     select grp.Key).Contains(o.NUMBER) == false
             select new { o, c }).ToList();
```

What I'd like to know is:

- What am I doing wrong?
- Can I optimize the query? Looks terrible, but I just haven't figured out a better way.

Comment: you can have a look at the generated Sql if you stop the debugger and add query to your watch list. Maybe that would help to get an idea what  is going wrong

Comment: Have you confirmed that `several conditions`/`bunch of conditions` don't contain the mismatch?

Comment: you cannot use the same alias on top and sub -queries, this could be a part of your issue. 
You have to provide use more info on your `WHERE` statement

Answer (score 1):

The queries you gave should be exactly the same, so I suspect that your translation of conditions is bad.  Most likely a mistake in case sensitivity or nullability.

You are doing a matrix join (or Cartesian join), then filtering by using a where clause.  You should convert this to a proper join (your original SQL should have done this as well, but it didn't) by using the "on" clause.  As you didn't supply the where conditions, I can't help you with that, but here is a semi-optimized version anyhow:

```
var query = (from o in context.ORDERS
             from c in context.CUSTOMERS
             where (bunch of conditions)
             group new {o,c} by o.NUMBER into grp
             where grp.Count() == 1
             select grp)
             .SelectMany(x=>x)
             .ToList();
```